# Error when creating login with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-signin

```
class login(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

This is the code that is meant to allow users to login to my website using their google account, but it gives me a server error. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What, specifically, is the error you're getting? The log will have more detail than you see in the browser, if you have debug mode turned off.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Login(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        greeting = '<a href="%s">Sign in</a>.' \
                   % users.create_login_url('/my_url')

        self.response.out.write('<html><body>%s</body></html>'
                                % greeting)
```

If it doesn't work, try clearing your browser cookie and cache.